# Insert Text to Legend

Tags: matlab

I am having a text with three lines that I would like to insert as a legend in my plots.

```
textLegend:
'Sentence 1'
'Sentence 2'
'Sentence 3'
```

Where one sentence may be

```
Sentence1 = 'pressure, Re= 10e5, std Re = 4e3'
```

Whenever I put legend(textLegend) I got

```
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.
```

Comment: Can u provide simple exmple of the plot and functions that u use?

Comment: I am using  simple plot function to see the lift and drag curves.  And the legend is like I showed you.

Comment: please post the exact code that you are using to display the legend.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you want to use:

```
legend(myCell)
```

where you can use a cell array like:

```
myCell={'My first sentence','pressure, Re= 10e5, std Re = 4e3'}
```

Well, if you use it like this, it should work, but the error message you got seems to come from somewhere else. As far as I see, you are using the function subsindex, and this function gets a cell-array. I would suggest to debug it, by stopping in the line, where the function subsindex is called.
Perhaps you can share some more code, if this doesnt help...

Answer (score 0):

legend(textLegend) with a cell array should be correct (presuming you are using the inbuilt function).

Double-check that you are not using legend as a variable name. I can replicate this error by defining a variable called legend (legend = [1 2 3] or similar) and then feeding it a cell array.

What happens is that Matlab assumes that by legend(textLegend), you mean the variable *legend* rather than the function, tries to call subsindex, and fails because you can't index a matrix with a cell array of strings.